# iOS 6 Constraints Making the UIView Longer

Tags: ios

I am not sure what is going on and how to handle this. I have a UIView in a cell and I set the constraints using IB and for some reason it stretches out to the end of the cell. How can I stop it from stretching.

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

I am dynamically injecting a stepper control but as you can see the UIView stretches to the end of the cell. I tried pin width then it completely messes up everything and does not even display the UIView.

Here is the screenshot of constraints:

[image]

Comment: If the stepper is supposed to cover the blue UIView perfectly, why do you need the blue UIView at all?

Comment: It does have to cover the blue UIView and the reason I have blue UIView is I am dynamically injecting the stepper on condition. As you can see the blue UIView expands to the right. How can I make it stop expanding and hitting the cell border.

Comment: But that is not a reason; you do not need the blue UIView in order to inject the stepper! Just inject the stepper, without the UIView. Is the problem that you do not understand how to add the stepper dynamically to the cell's `contentView`?

Comment: I know how to add stepper into the contentView but I like to add the stepper in place of UIView so I don't have to hardcode the coordinates.

Comment: What you're showing should work, so it's hard to tell what's going on without seeing all the constraints for the cell. Are you using a plain or grouped table view?

Comment: Plain. I updated the original question with constraints.

Comment: Why is the trailing space -388? That's wrong. It look like it should be about 20. I'm not sure how you set this up to get that large negative number. Try deleting that constraint and adding it back. How wide is this cell in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me draw some distinctions here.

- The *trivial* way to this is you *always* have the stepper in the cell (and no UIView). For those cells where we are not supposed to see the stepper, you set its `hidden` to YES; for those cells where we are supposed to see it, you set its `hidden` to NO. That is what I would do.
- The *programmer* way to do this is you *don't* have any blue UIView in your cell at all. You add the stepper in code, *and you also provide its constraints in code* to position it. You said:

  > so I don't have to hardcode the coordinates

  But adding constraints in code is *not* "hard coding" the coordinates. With constraints, you describe the position *conceptually* in terms of insets from the superview, and as the superview resizes, you are still correctly positioned. So there is no philosophical objection to adding the stepper and its constraints, and it is just laziness not to do that.
- The *lazy* but wasteful way is to do what you are doing, i.e. add the blue UIView in the nib as a guide. Even if you *do* use the blue UIView as a guide, though, you should be able to get this right if your constraints are right. I just tried this and I was not able to reproduce the problem: my blue view appeared in my cells in the same place where it appears in Interface Builder.
- The *instant* solution is don't use Autolayout in the nib from which a UITableViewCell is drawn — i.e. uncheck "Use autolayout" in the file inspector for this nib. You will thus use old-fashioned springs-and-struts (autoresizing) to position the subviews.

[image]

Comment: cannot uncheck auto layout!